# Sorting MVC razor UI table using Angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a requirement to sort a table in my MVC razor UI. The table was generated using scaffolding option in MVC and bound to a model. The code looks something like below

```
@model IEnumerable<Avanade.Bureau.DataAccessLayer.DatabaseModel.SubscriptionType>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Subscriptions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Subscriptions</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr ng-repeat="table in Model | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Subscribe", "Index", "Subscription", new { id = item.Id }, null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I want to use Angularjs to do sorting.All the examples that I have seen so far taken show examples of data that is hardcoded in the view. As you can see my view is bound to the model which gets the data from the database via the controller.  Could someone help.

Comment: You are crossing streams in your code. You don't want to have Razor loop through creating rows and then asking angular to create a bunch of table data. Use one or the other, you can still use razor file but drop the foreach keiv has it displayed well. Think of razor as a server side templating engine and angular as a client side. Make sure you are not trying to generate the same data on both sides.

Comment: http://wintellect.com/blogs/dbaskin/cookbook-for-asp-net-mvc-and-angular-js-web-apps perhaps these examples will help with your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by first initializing AngularJS data and then showing it:

```
@model IEnumerable<Avanade.Bureau.DataAccessLayer.DatabaseModel.SubscriptionType>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Subscriptions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<body ng-app ="ngAnimate">
<h2>Subscriptions</h2>
<div ng-init="data = [
     @foreach (var item in Model) {  
         <text>{id: '@item.Id' , code: '@item.Code' , description: '@item.Description' },</text>
     }
     ]">
</div>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="model in data">
    <td class="first">{{model.id}}</td>
    <td>{{model.code}}</td>
    <td>{{model.description}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```