# Simple MVC4 Razor Table UI Filtering using Angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a simpe MVC 4 application. this is my first ever ASP.NET MVC project and I completed the View-Controller-Model binding and getting  the results in he table format. Now my challenge is to filter the data using AngularJS. I googled a lot. All the examples I have seen so far are either advanced or hardcoded values in the app.js controller. Can someone please guide me how to implement the simple filtering using AngularJs. What do I need do achieve the same.

Below is my View (Index.html)

```
    @model IEnumerable<ProjectForm.Models.CreateProjectModel>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse Tasks";
    }
    @using System.Web.Optimization

    <h2>All Task List</h2>
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-nonfluid">
    <tr>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.task_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.task_desc)
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.task_type)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority)
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Task_status)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Requester)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequestDate)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.busowner)
        </th>
          <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.devowner)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.est_effort)
        </th>
         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Complete_date)
        </th>

         <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.act_effort)
        </th>

    </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.task_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.task_desc)
        </td>
                <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.task_type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Task_status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Requester)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestDate)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.busowner)
        </td>
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.devowner)
        </td>

          <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.est_effort)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Complete_date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.act_effort)
        </td>


    </tr>


}

</table>

</body>
```

I also found a most closest solution in Stack Overflow, but it is not complete. 
[Sorting MVC razor UI table using Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662914/sorting-mvc-razor-ui-table-using-angularjs/29734626#29734626)

Comment: you can´t compare Angular and ASP, Angular is a client side framework ASP MVC is server side. you cant link both

Comment: So,Is it not possible to use Angular Js for filtering a MVC table? If so the below solution sounds like it is possible.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662914/sorting-mvc-razor-ui-table-using-angularjs/29734626#29734626

Comment: angular does not uses MVC, MVC helps you to render HTML, then Angular works with HTML never with ASP